# Логика распределение данных по процентам

Tags: логика, php

Привет всем.

Есть 4 пользователя (может быть больше и меньше), и у них такие настройки процентов: 
1 - 30%
2 - 29%
3 - 1%
4 - 0%

Каждые пару минут (час-два) добавляется 1 запись в БД,
и итоге записей в конце дня должно быть распределено по равным процентам пользователя.
Можно, конечно, сортировать каждые 2-3 часа, брать записи, делить по процентам, но если записей будет меньше, чем пользователей.

Есть какие идеи над логикой, примеры?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Тут описывается алгоритм добавления записей, но на самом деле он не описывается, и непонятно, что отвечать.

Answer (score 1):

Каждый раз перед добавлением делайте запрос к базе, который будет возвращать только тех пользователей, для которых необходимо добавить записи, и далее добавляйте сами записи.

Comment: Как летать на самолете? - Тыкаешь пальцем на карту и летишь!  
ваш ответ ничего не объяснил, как вывести именно того польвотелЯ тд

Comment: Как вопрос поставлен, так ответ и дан. Как можно что-то расчитывать, не зная, на какие данные надо опираться?
В sql Вы можете выполнять простые математические операции, вот и выбирайте те записи, где кол-во записей на пользователя в процентном соотношении меньше, чем должно быть.